# Would these ingredients work for a Gift In a Jar?

Tags: baking, storage-method

I am planning on making a Gift In a Jar for a cake. An example of a Gift In a Jar can be found [here](http://tipnut.com/free-gifts-in-a-jar-recipes/). Basically I would be putting the following ingredients in the jar:

- Flour
- Cocoa
- Baking powder
- Baking soda
- Salt
- Cinnamon
- White sugar
- Brown sugar
- Chopped Almonds

The recipe just calls for me to put all the ingredients into a bowl, mix and pour into a pan. No seperation of dry and wet ingredients here. The other ingredients that aren't included in this list is shredded zucchini, orange zest, milk, vanilla, eggs and oil.

Would this work together?? Are there any specific ingredients that I should leave out? How far in advance could I put it all together?

Comment: I don't suppose you have a recipe in mind that you could point us to?  Sugar usually goes in with the wet ingredients, so this could be a problem, but maybe there are certain types of cakes where you can just dump it all into the mixing bowl...

Comment: Sorry don't have the recipe online. Basically you mix all the ingredients together and pour into the pan. Simpliest ever!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of those ingredients should be fine.  The only thing you really have to worry about is shelf life, so make sure to buy fresh ingredients and check your expiration dates, especially on the baking powder and baking soda and the almonds.  I would just tell them to use it within a year (or the earliest expiration date).

Oh yeah, and don't put the baking powder and baking soda next to the brown sugar.  There isn't a lot of water in it, but it might be enough to cause issue.